# Page not refreshing after href-link

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've got a page listing a number of items in two tables. We'll call them Recent and Saved. The tables list some data about each item and each row contains a "remove" link. The link goes back to the same page with some extra data in the link.

The links work just fine. The problem is that about half of the time when a link is clicked, the page doesn't refresh. It looks like nothing happened. If you manually refresh then the page updates accordingly.

Now what's really strange is that the code for both Recent and Saved is the same. However, it seems that it always works fine for Saved, whereas I have this problem with Recent.

HTML code:

```
<td><a class="confirmation"
href="path/to/site/list.php?delete=yes&id=<? echo $data['id']; ?>"
OnClick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">remove</a></td>
```

JavaScript code:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('confirmation');
var confirmOne = function(e){
    if(!confirm("Are you sure?")) e.preventDefault();
};
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', confirmIt);
}
```

Any ideas as to why it refreshes the page sometimes, but not others?

Update: There are a couple problems with the code, which I have since fixed as per the comments. Unfortunately these problems aren't causing my main issue, and fixing them has done nothing to solve it.

Comment: Yu're calling wrong function: elements[i].addEventListener('click', __confirmIt__);
var __confirmOne__ = function(e)

Comment: You do not have a function called confirmIt. You have a var called confirmOne

Comment: Each link has an onclick attribute and you are adding another event listener through javascript?

Comment: Not true. A function can be declared as a variable. The point is - I think - the third line in the JavaScript code. Just change it to: return confirm('Are you sure?'); That should do the trick.

Comment: @MehmetSÖĞÜNMEZ and mplungjan: you were both right. The function name was wrong, so the function wasn't even being called.

Comment: @Will: you are right too... I didn't realize that the confirm dialogue returning false would prevent the link from firing. So it seems I don't even need any JS? If I do, I don't need the onclick. Not entirely sure why I had both at once. Fixed the first issue, and now I'm getting two confirm dialogs. Unfortunately, none of these fixes do anything to solve the problem I posted about in the first place: the page refresh issue. It doesn't refresh most of the time, even with these fixes.

Comment: @JanWillem: your proposed solution doesn't seem to change anything either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although some users pointed out some flaws and mistakes in my code, none of them were able to solve the actual issue I was asking about. I never did find out how to fix it or what the cause was.

In the end, I just ended up using AJAX to reload the content. It was the much better solution, anyways. It looks and works much better now, and there is no refresh. The new code looks something like this:

HTML:

```
<td><a OnClick="deleteOne(<? echo $data['id']; ?>)">remove</a></td>
```

JavaScript:

```
function deleteOne(id){
    if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
        var selector = "#" + id;
        $.get(
            "path/to/site/list.php",
            {delete: "yes", id: id},
            function(){
                $("#my-content").load(location.href+" #my-content>*","");
            }
        );
    }
}
```